# In winforms, on keydown event handler textbox event keypress is not working

Tags: c#, winforms

In winform application, I am using a key down event to proceed to next field. It works properly but i want to handle an event of text box here as well like key press. If key down event on the form is available then key press event is not fired.
How can i resolve it.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You will need to post some code. Also have you set the forms `KeyPreview` property to true?

Comment: Did you tried in keyup_Down event?

Comment: Do you process the keydown event at the form level (KeyPreview=True) and do you want to process the same key at KeyPress event of a particolar TextBox?

Comment: Yes keypreview is true. And if i make the KeyPreview property set to false the KeyPress of text box is in voked. But i want to use both handlers.

Comment: if(e.keycode == keys.Enter || e.keycode == TAB) { e.SuppressKeyPress; e.Handled == true ; this.SelectNextControl(this.ActiveControl, true,true,true,true) } this is the which i am using to proceed to next control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every KeyDown event receive a [KeyEventArgs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.windows.forms.keyeventargs.handled%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) parameter.
Inside the KeyEventArgs parameter there is a property named SuppressKeyPress.
[According to MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.windows.forms.keyeventargs.suppresskeypress%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) setting this property to true avoid the KeyPress event
If you set this property to false, **the current control with focus** will receive the keypress.

```
private void formMain_KeyDown(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs e)
{
    // Do your processing
    ....
    e.Handled = true;
    e.SuppressKeyPress = false;
}
```